# Web page caching -- is it possible to NOT cache portions of a page, but cache the rest?

Tags: html, wordpress, caching, cloudflare

I maintain a WordPress website for a small TV station. It contains "tune in information" that is updated dynamically typically at the top or bottom of every hour (depending on when a 30-minute show / hour episode / two-hour movie ends).

We want to use browser caching, but if we do that, the end user won't see the most up-to-date information until we publish out a piece of content.

As a result, we're currently caching image assets and the like, but we aren't caching HTML.

Is there a way to take advantage of page caching while still having portions of the page update in real-time?

For what it's worth, we use CloudFlare and can cache through that and we also use Hummingbird Pro and could use that for page caching.